# Post data with jquery ajax and overwrite/write file in external file

Tags: jquery, ajax, overwrite

I have a problem with overwriting/writing file by sending data from an each function through jquery ajax. I think my post.php isn't correct can some help me with this feature?

```
$('.mod').each(function(){  
  var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "post.php",    
            data: "divid="+id+"&length="+$('.mod').length+"&ok=1",
            success: function(msg){  }
    });
 });

    if($_POST['ok']==1){        
                $File ='index.php';
    $Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
    $length = $_POST['length'] ;
    fwrite($Handle, ''.$_POST['divid'].'<br>');
    fclose($Handle); 
}
```

Regards Frank

Comment: Try to call post.php directly and see whether it contains any errors. As you can see in the syntax highlighting, there is a syntax error in the fwrite() line

Comment: Oh sorry it was a ' that made the error but this doesn't solve my problem. I have to make something with Json if I'm correct. All ids have to return in the file but how. Now I get only the latest id in the file

Answer (score 2):

serialize the data and send it to the php rather than doing each function

```
var ids = $("input[name='ids']").serializeArray();
```

like this just take the data into a variable and post it to php... not the whole form details only checkbox details

Comment: Can't serialize it because all elements are appended in a form. When I serialize the form it won't give me a datastring.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction, I used JSON now :) a different way.

Comment: @Frank .... You use a different way.... COOL! but that means you can't accept an answer?? terrific.